# Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops, subquery

I need to set up a job in SQL Server 2008 to run at the first of the month sending an email to our customers. However, I do not know how to loop through the results of the subquery.

Resulting in this error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
>   or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression.

Here's the relevant code:

```
SET @Recipients =(SELECT DISTINCT a.EMail
         FROM   a
        --approximately 600 email addresses 

SET @MailSubject = 'Customer News' 
SET @MailRecipients = @Recipients
SET @MailMessage =  'Dear customer, Attached is your customer news letter.'

SET @FileName = N'E:file\to\be\attached.doc'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = @MailRecipients, 
    @body = @MailMessage,
    @blind_copy_recipients='misj@mikl.org', 
    @subject = @MailSubject,
    @file_attachments  = @FileName
```

Comment: This *may* be a place to consider using the rarely-a-good-choice CURSOR (if the operation has become imperative and is no longer set-based). However, SQL Server also supports Table Variables [discussed here vs. CURSOR](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TableVariablesVSCursor.aspx). One `INSERTS INTO` Table Variables. What is the *signature* of the `sp_send_dbmail` procedure? (This will lead to better answers, not just "why it doesn't work" ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The error is here where you have many rows trying to be assigned to a single variable

```
SET @Recipients =(SELECT DISTINCT a.EMail
     FROM   a
    --approximately 600 email addresses
```

You'd need to change it to a separated list thus

```
SET @Recipients = STUFF(
           (select DISTINCT ';' + CAST(a.EMail AS varchar(max))
           FROM a FOR XML PATH ('')
           )
          ,1,1, '')
```

Note: @Recipients will need to be varchar(max)

Comment: Thank you. It appeared to only send the second email address listed and truncate the first letter of the email address.

Comment: @Mikki: I can't test (no SQL Server to hand) but the XML PATH should generate a full list like this http://blog.programmingsolution.net/sql-server-2008/comma-separated-list-csv-of-rows-of-a-column-using-for-xml-path/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `@recipients = @MailRecipients`. It is expecting a string (an email address) and you are giving it a recordSet.

Comment: How would you correct this? Can I set this stored procedure up to loop through the record set?

Comment: The error occurs way before that in the SET @Recipients call... the stored proc call is OK