# Subquery returned more than 1 value. VB6

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I'm trying to select the value of `movementline.qty` but only if `movements.movementscode` is equal to RW if not just put 0.00

```
SELECT levelfield1.description,
       products.reportuom,
       products.productcode,
       products.description,
       Isnull(Sum(ReceivingLine.qty), 0.00)       AS [B.Delivery],
       movements.movementcode,
       Isnull((SELECT qty
               FROM   MovementLine
               WHERE  movementcode = 'RW'), 0.00) AS [B. Returned]
FROM   Products
       LEFT JOIN LevelField1
              ON levelfield1.levelfield1code = products.levelfield1code
       LEFT JOIN ReceivingLine
              ON receivingline.PRODUCTCODE = products.productcode
       LEFT JOIN MovementLine
              ON movementline.ProductCode = products.productcode
       LEFT JOIN Movements
              ON movements.MovementID = MovementLine.movementid
GROUP  BY levelfield1.Description,
          products.reportuom,
          products.productcode,
          products.description,
          movementline.qty,
          movements.movementcode
```

I got error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or
>   other SET operation.

Comment: What if movements.movementscode is equal to RW returns more than one row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subquery returned more than 1 value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115797/subquery-returned-more-than-1-value)

Comment: To start with never use a correlated subquery. They are performance killers. This can be done through joins  to the base tables or to a derived table if calculationss need to be done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code make to think deeply. Because there maybe join problem and you may not get correct result. Problem will solve using top 1 but correct result will not possible. So here need to use CASE.
I hope your problem will solve by using bellow code.

```
select levelfield1.description, products.reportuom, products.productcode,
        products.description ,ISNULL(SUM(ReceivingLine.qty),0.00) as [B.Delivery], 
  movements.movementcode,
  CASE 
    WHEN movementline.movementcode = 'RW' THEN ISNULL(movementline.qty,0.00)
    ESLE 0.00
  END AS [Returned]

  from Products 
  left join LevelField1 on levelfield1.levelfield1code = products.levelfield1code
  left join ReceivingLine on receivingline.PRODUCTCODE = products.productcode
  left join MovementLine on movementline.ProductCode = products.productcode
  left join Movements on movements.MovementID = MovementLine.movementid 
  group by levelfield1.Description, products.reportuom, products.productcode, products.description, movementline.qty,movements.movementcode
```

Comment: thanks, but movementsline is a many to one relationship to products, can I sum the total value of movementline qty?